# Different fonts in MaTeX

Tags: graphics, fonts, matex

I have read [this link](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html) but can't quite figure out how to use a different font in MaTeX. Would someone be kind enough to provide a complete example for the following context

```
Graphics[Inset[MaTeX["\\sin(x)", Magnification -> 4], {3, 1}, {0, 0}]]
```

Also, the following questions occur to me:

1. Can I use *any* font installed on my system (MacOS)?
2. Even a Hershey font?
3. Will the necessary metrics be recalculated for the given font?

Could you also include the code that illustrates how to use xelatex?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This is all covered in the MaTeX documentation, did you check it?

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you for your answer below!  How does one know that there is MaTeX documentation? I did "??MaTeX", but that yielded nothing. Same thing happened whey I searched for MaTeX in the Documentation Center. I also tried "http://reference.wolfram.com/MaTeX/guide/MaTeX", as well as typing "MaTeX/guide/MaTeX" in the search/address bar of the documentation window in Mathematica. Perhaps downloading the documentation from Github is best?

Comment: Did you search in your web browser or did you use the documentation center in the Help menu?

Comment: "How does one know that there is MaTeX documentation?" It's clearly written on the page you linked ... scroll to "Usage".  If you type `?MaTeX`, there will be a small blue `>>` sign after the usage message. Clicking it opens the help.  Don't search on wolfram.com online. That's Wolfram's documentation.  Click Help -> Documentation Center, and search there.  You do have the latest version of the package, 1.7.0, right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is all covered in the built-in documentation.  Search for MaTeX in Mathematica's documentation centre, or type in the following address: `MaTeX/guide/MaTeX`.  But I will give some examples here anyway:

How to set a given font is really a LaTeX question.  You will find many fonts samples with instructions on how to use them at [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/).  Usually, you need to add a package to the preamble.  For example, to use Utopia Regular with Fourier math,

```
MaTeX["\\text{If $x=2$ then $x^2=4$.}", 
 "Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage{fourier}"}, Magnification -> 4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is covered under the examples for the `"Preamble"` option in the `MaTeX` doc page, as well as in the Typesetting with MaTeX tutorial.

To use XeTeX, you need to configure MaTeX to use the appropriate executable.  This is covered in the `ConfigureMaTeX` documentation page.  I will copy the example from that page here:

```
ConfigureMaTeX["pdfLaTeX" -> "/Library/TeX/texbin/xelatex"]

MaTeX["\\text{Beautiful typesetting}",
 "Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage{fontspec}", "\\setmainfont{Zapfino}"},
 FontSize -> 24
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course, the path to the `xelatex` executable will be specific to your system.

Remember that `ConfigureMaTeX` will change the configuration permanently.  Restarting Mathematica will not reset it.  If you need to change back to plain LaTeX, you must do it manually.

[With XeLaTeX you can use any installed system font.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3393/what-is-xetex-exactly-and-why-should-i-use-it) This is generally useful for text mode only. To use a system font in math mode, you need a font with special math support, such as Cambria Math.  Here's an example:

```
MaTeX["\\text{Foo $x^2$ bar}",
 "Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage{fontspec,unicode-math}", 
   "\\setmainfont{Cambria}", "\\setmathfont{Cambria Math}"},
 Magnification -> 4
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I am not experienced with Unicode math fonts. If you have more questions about them, I suggest asking on [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you, very helpful! Is there a list of fonts with special math support?

Comment: @Lem.ma I don't know, you'd have to google ...